# How to check if string is present in bash array using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I've got a file that looks like this:

```
a    12345
b    3456
c    45678
```

and i've got bash array of strings:

```
mylist=("a" "b")
```

What I want to do is to sum numbers in second column but only for rows where first column value (aka "a" or "b") is present in `mylist`.

My not-working code:

```
cat myfile.txt | awk -F'\t' '{BEGIN{sum=0} {if ($1 in ${mylist[@]}) sum+=$2} END{print sum}}'
```

Expected result is 12345+3456=15801.
I understand that problem is in if-statement but can't figure out how to rearrange this code to work.

Comment: awk can't see bash variables; they're two different interpreters in two different processes. It's not clear how you'd expect this to work -- and you don't _need_ awk for the job you're doing anyhow; native bash can do it just fine.

Comment: Or if you want something faster than native bash when operating on very large input files, the standard UNIX toolkit has `join`, perfectly well-suited to extracting only the lines you care about.

Comment: Thanks, Shawn, yes it was my typo, i didn't use them in original code, edited it

Comment: (And if you want to quickly check if a bash array contains a string, you should make it an _associative_ array with that string as the key instead of the value; that way it's an O(1) lookup instead of an O(n) one).

Comment: you actually think an approach involving unnecessary pre-sorting is a good solution to big data joining ? ha

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto First, `sort` parallelizes well: on a multi-core machine, given a seekable input, it partitions it and does a merge sort between the partitions. Second, if your input is big enough that that matters, then you probably don't want to need to store that input in memory, and both GNU sort and `join` have bounded memory usage. Third, sorting _at runtime_ is a fallback; if folks actually care, they keep their data sorted ahead-of-time. `join` itself has a worst-case that's basically `O(n+m)`, and memory-wise `O(1)`; compared to an awk approach where your memory is O(n) at best.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto, ...which is to say: Yes, I do (subject to certain assumptions about input sizes, memory availability, etc), and I can defend that position. :)

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto, ...keeping large data pre-sorted is important for a lot more tools than `join`; there are extremely efficient `grep` alternatives that rely on being sorted by the key one searches by, f/e. It's basically the poor person's alternative to using an indexed database with the sort field as the primary key. :)

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto, ...see https://github.com/pts/pts-line-bisect -- the tool I was referencing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : then i'd say `awk` must be quite decent of a solution considering one needs `C-code` binaries just to beat it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : and you just described the exact approach I use for my lyrics translation file, which maps 12.5 million lines of lyrics from 4 different languages, each to the other 3. It wasn't easy routing 37.5 million queries via the free Google Translation API without getting throttled. But sometimes Google really gets on my nerves - like lyrics lines that go `oh ! oh ! oh!` and Google literally translated those to `Ohio! Ohio! Ohio!` in Chinese for me <facepalm>

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : yeah pre-sorting without using indexing is only good if you're always joining in the exact same column order. To your other statement - a full-scale `RDBMS`, even if they're open sourced, still comes with its own set of nuances, where all querying and updating need to involve precise `SQL` syntax, whereas appending rows to the tail of a `.txt` file using `awk` is totally a piece of cake. like i said - it's only 12.5 million rows of lyrics - that itself doesn't make any `RDBMS` or even Hadoop worth its while. Anything short of `20 GB` - might as well `.txt` file it all the way.

Comment: This isn't the place for the discussion, but I don't concede that one needs nonstandard tools written in C to get more desirable behavior than awk. _This particular question_ is a place where the awk approach should be fine, though, because even if the file is large, the array should always fit in memory; but when you're trying to join two inputs that are _both_ too large to fit in memory, then awk can become quickly unsuitable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : and ps : it's not about how much one can parallelize it - sorting is `O(n log n)` (give or take), so it should always be avoided whenever possible, or at least deferred downstream. Pre-sorting input data should be a last resort unless absolutely no viable alternative exists. case in point - if u have 2 filtering criteria, each requiring a column from a different table, one can pay the high price up front, pre-sort, join, then filter, or one can pre-filter at each source table before joining, which likely saves a lot.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : any `.txt` file below `3 GB` isn't "large" in `awk`'s eyes.

Comment: 3GB is large to awk if you're on a system with 2GB of RAM, and you're loading that file into an associative array (does awk call those maps? adjust terminology as appropriate) to use when processing a second file. Again, it's all about how the data sizes compare to your available memory.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto, as for "pay a high price up-front" to pre-sort, it depends on how often you edit your data. Edit it once a day and query every few seconds? Then that up-front price is _deeply_ worth it! And once the data is sorted, you can add new data _into_ the set with a merge sort; it's only the initial sort that has to be done with a slower algorithm.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto... yeah, `O(n log n)` is unavoidable -- the point about partitioning is that `sort` can sort data _larger than available memory_ by splitting out into temporary files, sorting them individually and doing a merge sort between them (which GNU sort does automatically, under the hood, when data gets too large). awk _can't_ join two things where both are larger than memory. So this is a place where sort+join can do things awk is completely 100% incapable of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no good reason to make awk read the array in the first place. Let `join` quickly pick out the matching lines -- that's what it's specialized to do.

And if in real life your array and input file keys are guaranteed to be sorted as they are in the example, you can take the `sort` uses out of the code below.

```
# Cautious code that doesn't assume input sort order
LC_ALL=C join -1 1 -2 1 -o1.2 \
  <(LC_ALL=C sort <myfile.txt) \
  <(printf '%s\n' "${mylist[@]}" | LC_ALL=C sort) \
  | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
```

...or...

```
# Fast code that requires both the array and the file to be pre-sorted
join -1 1 -2 1 -o1.2 myfile.txt <(printf '%s\n' "${mylist[@]}") \
  | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing it in pure bash by making the elements of the original array keys in an associative one:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mylist=(a b)

# Use the elements of the array as the keys in an associative array
declare -A keys
for elem in "${mylist[@]}"; do
    keys[$elem]=1
done


declare -i sum=0
# Read the lines on standard input
# For example, ./sum.sh < input.txt
while read -r name num; do
    # If the name is a key in the associative array, add to the sum
    if [[ -v keys[$name] ]]; then
        sum+=$num
    fi
done

printf "%d\n" "$sum"
```

Comment: Maybe also show the alternative `declare -A keys=([a]=1 [b]=1)` defining an associative array up-front, vs starting from an indexed array and transforming?

Answer (score 2):

One method would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

mylist=(a b)

awk '
    FNR==NR { a[$1]; next }
    $1 in a { sum += $2 }
        END { print sum }
' <(printf '%s\n' "${mylist[@]}") file
```

Note that, when initializing an array in `bash`, array elements are separated by whitespaces, not commas.